# Dynamic content web scraping with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, pyqt4

if i run below code getting below error. can you please help me with these problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dynamic.py", line 20, in <module>
    client_response = Client(url)
TypeError: QWebPage(QObject parent=None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

> code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage
import bs4 as bs


class Client(QWebPage):
    def _int_(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage._init_(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_page_load)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()
    def on_page_load(self):
        self.app.quit()

url = "https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/"
client_response = Client(url)
source = client_response.mainFrame().toHtml()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
js_test = soup.find('p', class_='jstest')
print(js_test.text)
```

> modified:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage
import bs4 as bs


class Client(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_page_load)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()
    def on_page_load(self):
        self.app.quit()

url = "https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/"
client_response = Client(url)
source = client_response.mainFrame().toHtml()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
js_test = soup.find('p', class_='jstest')
print(js_test.text)
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? It should be `__init__` not `_init_`

Comment: And your original function, which is called `_int_`, did you rename that to `__init__` also?

Comment: yes, i modified.

Comment: `QWebPage._init_(self)` should be `QWebPage.__init__(self)`

Comment: Modified code i added. Please check and find out the problem.